# Adding Gmail from Online Accounts in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, gmail

I noticed that in the "Online Accounts" application that you can add Gmail, Yahoo etc and it says you can add your email. Especially for the GMail it says under it "Includes Gmail, Google+, Picasa, Google Docs etc..."

Goes not add your gmail account to the local machine anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but Google has added the kitchen sink, i.e., multiple Google online services, all managed with the same authentication. Add the mail, you get the rest.